# Open StreetMap Reverse Geocoding

Tags: geolocation, openstreetmap

Does anyone know of any open source projects that will allow reverse geocode lookups over Open StreetMap data?

I'd prefer not to use an existing hosted webservice such as [Nominatim](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim) since my dataset is large.

Answer (score 3):

You can install [Nominatim](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim) on your own, it can do [reverse geocoding](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim#Reverse_Geocoding_.2F_Address_lookup) pretty well. There is also a Nomiatim instance hosted by [MapQuest](http://open.mapquestapi.com/nominatim/) with a less strict usage policy.

Answer (score 2):

there is also [Gisgraphy](http://www.gisgraphy.com) that use openstreetmap data and geonames. it got 5 web services (geocoding, reverse geocoding, fulltext search, find near by, address parser) and all can be done offline. it is free, opensources, and a demo is available at [services.gisgraphy.com](http://services.gisgraphy.com)