# Is there any way around to get Zip & address using latitude and longitude in windows phone 7.1 ?

Tags: windows-phone-7, location, windows-phone-7.1, zipcode, windows-phone-7.1.1

I have used Bing Maps key reversegeocode for getting address & I am getting the desired result also but it needs bing key that expires in 90 days.So its not better method to use.

I have also tried CivicAddressResolver to get the same but its not returning any address.I don know why.

I have also tried google api for the same i am getting answer but it has usage limitation that it can be used 2500 times per day.

Lastly i have tried ReverseGeocodeQuery method to get the same but its working fine only with windows phone version 8.

i need the same to happen with windows phone version 7.1 .

Plz reply.

thanks in advance.

Comment: will this help you ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11118061/open-streetmap-reverse-geocoding

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use an alternative service for getting the Zip code/address. The question Rohith links to in the comment has a good alternative: [Nominatim](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim#Reverse_Geocoding_.2F_Address_lookup). Another alternative is also [Geonames](http://www.geonames.org/export/reverse-geocoding.html) which also has some reverse geocoding.

Comment: the problem with all these free services is the reliability :( . I chose one for decoding the simple country code and it happened to be offline after a few days.. So use with caution

Answer (score 0):

Google probably has the best service, and is free for the first 6 months, and $10/month after that. It's a very reasonable price, and with 99.9% uptime and fast servers, it's tonnes better than you will get from any free service or even most other paid ones.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/geolocation/

If you're desperate for free ones, I have heard that Geonames is okay. Still, you're not going to beat what Google can give you for a very modest price. It should be noted that you have to pay excess if you go above 10,000 requests per month, but if your app is that popular, you can monetize it to subsidise...

**Edit**
Just noticed that you already mentioned Google, but like I said, what does it matter if it costs a bit if you're anticipating anywhere near 2,500 requests per day?!?